# Printer printing in blue and pink

Tags: windows, printing, printer, adobe-acrobat

I have hp 3635 printer and I am out of black ink. I am trying to print the rest of pdf text file with the color ink and I fail to see an option in acrobat reader to choose specific color. I need to print in blue only but the printer is printing a line in blue and a line in pink. How can I get it to print in blue only?

Comment: Install an HP driver (written by Microsoft) for an HP printer connected to a Windows NT 4.0 computer.  Confirm that the printer is certified by Microsoft to be fully compatible with Windows NT 4.0.  It will only print in black and blue.  Neither Microsoft nor HP will fix it to work with other colors, nor admit that they falsely advertised it as being compatible.  Your problem is solved.  My problem was solved by never buying another HP printer again.

Answer (score 1):

I should start by saying that printing in "blue" is not an option on any printer. The printer itself will refuse to print when one of its inks is empty, regardless of what the driver tells it. Also, blue is not one of the printer's colours. Printer inks are of the colours cyan (light blue), magenta (purplish red) and yellow. Blue is printed by putting cyan and magenta in the same pixel.

The only exception here are some (rare) printers that let you print black-only documents when one or more of the colour inks are empty. If the printer can do that, there is usually a special setting in the driver for it. Start by setting the driver to black & white or greyscale from Printer Properties. Then go through the other tabs to see if you can find additional settings like "run black". But of course, you are out of black.

Comment: The problem is that the printer is printing in random colors(blue and pink). Sometimes it prints the front page in blue alone which is exactly what I want, but then it print the back with total pink. Sometimes it prints a line in blue and line in pink. I dont know how to control it.

Comment: How do the hardware test pages look? As your problem seems to be intermittent, try several tests, as follows. Press and hold the Power button, and then press the Cancel button. Let go of Cancel, then let go of Power. See https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04617078

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Reader does not have an option to print using only a certain *colour*, with exception of forcing use of greyscale.

It's unusual to have the option to print a colour document in colours *different* than those specified in the document. However, if such an option is available to you, it will be in the properties of your printer, which you can access through the Print dialog when printing your document.